# How to free scene until Interstitial is dismissed?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, admob, interstitial

So I have a an app that uses interstitial ads. Specifically it is a a SpriteKit game written with Swift.

I have code setup that when the user presses the replay button from the game over scene an ad appears and then it changes back to the game scene to replay the game. Now where I am running into problems the scene changes while the interstitial ad is being displayed, sometimes this doesn't happen fast enough and user can tap the restart button again, causing the game to crash.

Is there a way to freeze the screen and ignore any taps while the ad is being called? And also to only have the scene change after the ad is dismissed?

The code when the restart button is pressed;

```
 if restartButton.contains(pointOfTouch) {
    score = 0
    ballMovementSpeed = 2
    displayAd()
    delay(2.0) {
    self.restartScene()
 }
```

I am a bit confused as to where the interstitialDelegate is placed. I am trying to implement func interstitialDidDismissScreen(ad: GADInterstitial!) {} to trigger a change back to my game scene and nothing happens when I dismiss the ad.

I have tried placing it in override func didMove(to view: SKScene){} as well as when the restart button is pressed and still won't work. This is how i have the ad being called

```
fun loadAndShow() {
  myAd = GADInterstitial()
  let requestI = GADRequest()
  myAd.setAdUnitID("adID")
  requestI.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID, "test device"]
  myAd.delegate = self
  myAd.load(requestI)
}

func interstitialDidReceiveAd(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
  if (self.myAd.isReady) {
    myAd.present(fromRootViewController: self)
  }
}
```

Comment: code please.....

Comment: Hello Simone Pistecchia I have added the code

Comment: I think you must remove delay(2.0)  self.restartScene(). There is a delegate when the ad was dismiss, use that function to restart the scene

Comment: Where do I place this delegate? I have already removed the delay but the delegate does not work.

Comment: func interstitialDidDismissScreen(_ ad: GADInterstitial!)    source: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/ios/api/reference/Protocols/GADInterstitialDelegate

Comment: This is what I used I know the code for it but where do I put this in my code. I put it in the `GameViewController` and it didn't work. I placed it in my `GameOverScene` and it didn't work. I placed it in and outside of the `didMoveToView`.

Comment: I don't know if I've understood well your problem. This func must put where is your myAd var. the code "myAd.delegate = self" the self is the class, you must have that class with GADAdLoaderDelegate

Comment: I will edit this code later to show the two files and how I coded the interstitial to appear.

Answer (score 1):

you can use delegate methods of admob so when interstitial is going to be shown you can remove the restart button or put a condition so that it would not work when ad is shown. Also to pause the game is also important if it is running using isPaused bool.
https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/ad-events

Comment: if this provides the answer you can accept this as answer.